# Should we give page numbers to each pages of the research paper?

Tags: paper-submission, conference

I had finished writing a research paper for a conference. Should I give page numbers to each of the pages.

This question look so dumb. But,
I am asking this because, whenever we download any research paper from the internet, we usually see the page numbers which are provided by Journals or Conference proceedings.

So is author need to provide page numbers at the bottom of the page? Or they will reserved this place for page numbering by them?

Comment: Do you not have any kind of supervisor, superior or senior colleague to turn to for just these kind of questions? And it doesn't matter if you put page numbers or not.

Comment: Is this in a field like CS where you submit entire papers to a conference, or a field where you are just submitting an abstract?

Comment: If your paper is divided into sufficiently short (1-2 page) sections and subsections, then (sub)section numbers would almost universally replace the need for page numbers. Based on your user name, math papers frequently refer only to theorem and equation numbers, rather than the pages on which theorems and equations appear on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two issues. The version submitted to the conference might, at a later stage, be reformatted for publication in proceedings or journals. But both versions should have page numbers.

Page numbers even in a "for review" version help reviewers with any comments back to you and generally ease the work flow. Those page numbers aren't for formal citation since this is pre-publication.

I also think that any *published* paper longer than a couple of pages should have page numbers to aid readers in making citations to specific parts of your paper.

My experience is that conferences usually want PDF submissions and most people prepare these from a document created by some document editor in which page numbers are easy to add. You may be asked for an edited version later that requires some sort of formatting either with or without page numbers. Follow those directions, of course.

For international submissions, note that page numbering might need to change for final copy. Pagination in 8.5 x 11 won't likely be the same as A4, for example.

---

I would worry, actually, about conferences that want editable documents for review purposes. If they are, in fact, edited by others, they might change your intent. Journals may need editable documents to allow copy editing and formatting for consistency, but there, the ones doing changes are professionals at that task and, hopefully, get your signify on any changes.

Comment: Sir, In their brochure they mentioned that, some best papers after reviewing are published in Journals.

Answer (score 12):

If you are asking this question, that suggests that you are using a document without a style file, or a style file of your own. But you should be using the style file that is appropriate for the conference, and that style file will either include page numbers or it will not -- in either case, you should leave it as is, as the people who created the style file have made the decision for you (along with all of the other things such as which font, font size, etc., to use for section headings and figure captions).

Comment: No they didn't provide any style file. Except some formatting instructions. These instructions exclude page numbers too.

Comment: Then you just do what seems like the right thing. Since every journal and every book you will have ever seen has page numbers, using page numbers yourself should be the pretty obvious thing to do.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, please include page numbers in your papers. I’ve never seen a research paper that didn’t have page numbers, and if I saw one I would get quite annoyed and disoriented. Page numbers are simply useful.

In the preprint phase, page numbers should start at 1. When your paper is published in a journal or conference proceedings, the publisher will adjust the page numbers to suit the location of your paper in the journal or proceedings volume. That’s not something you need to worry about right now.

Comment: In combination with the comment that states that a style file is *not* provided, this is the right answer. Imagine if the paper was printed and then dropped - you'd want page numbers then! But I'd add: please include page numbers using a method that makes them easy for any future typesetter to change/remove (that is, don't add them manually! Know how to use your editing tool so you don't have to do this).

Comment: Sir, Yes I see. Your answer is short and beautiful and straight to the point. But unfortunately I can't accept it as a answers, as we can't change accepted answer. Still I had upvoted your answer. Thank you.

Comment: @GeneralMathematics As the OP, you are the only person who *can* accept a different answer.